# URL of images added by KCFinder are wrong

Tags: wordpress, kcfinder

When I click Browse Server within the Image Properties modal, I can see the list of images (the URL is correct). However, after clicking on an image to be added to the editor, the URL becomes incorrect. For some reason KCFinder removes `wp` from `wp-content`. The URL something like this: https://mysite.local/-content/uploads/civicrm/persist/contribute/images/image.png

Answer (score 2):

Problem fixed overriding `['cms.root']['path']` on civicrm.settings.php file.

Answer (score 1):

Can you check your resource URL settings?

CiviCRM >> Administer >> System Settings >> Resource URL.

Comment: CiviCRM Resource URL: https://mysite.local/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm. Image Upload URL: [civicrm.files]/persist/contribute/

Comment: @Predeep Nayak, I believe the problem is `[civicrm.files]/persist/contribute/`. Inside file public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/kcfinder/integration/civicrm.php, it's returning the wrong path (/-content/uploads/civicrm/persist/contribute/). But when I run the function `Civi::paths()->getUrl("[civicrm.files]/persist/contribute/")` in the functions.php of my theme, I got the correct path.